Python Mako: JS not working in rendered html
I have got the following folder structure
daemon.py  
template.mako  
html/  
  main.html  
  javascript/  
    script.js

Now my daemon is running a wsgi server, using bottle. The endpoint does the following:
@route("/main")
def main():
    lookup = TemplateLookup(directories=["html", "html/javascript"])

    return Template(filename="template.mako", lookup=lookup).render()

The mako template now includes the main.html (which contains the header) and does some looped function execution, rendering a card item from bulma for each turn of the loop. A button is supposed to be expanding the card via the script.js. The latter in turn is included via <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/script.js"></script>.
I've tried many different ways of providing the right path in src and also moving the <script> element from main.html to template.mako. The site itself is rendering just fine, correctly including the header. But besides the 200 for the site itself, I always get a 404 for the script upon loading the page.
Does anyone have an idea, what I am doing wrong?

You need endpoint to serve assets, ie. The JavaScript file.  I would try opening the js file in the browser first. Here is their example:
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#serving-assets

Thanks, I guess that would have worked. I switched to flask though, having it used before and not liking bottle all too much...
